# Xcode 4.3.3 compiling project -> Build Succeeded but Phonegap-App wont get installed on iPhone 3G

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

the problem is described in the header. The architecture in the Build Settings is set to (armv 7) $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT). armv6 doesnt work either. The device is running iOS 4.2.1. I updated my Xcode today and since then it doesnt run on the 3G anymore, however it works on the 4S with iOS 5.1. The App is developed with Phonegap

Anybody has experienced this and knows how to avoid it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you or your update make any change to the target OS? 

With armv7 you should be fine for 3G or newer devices.

Comment: Recheck your Xcode setting to make sure it is set for minimum iOS 4.x...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The armv7 works from 3GS onwards, not for the 3G. Unfortunately I cannot edit the comment above any more.

Comment: the target is set to 3.0. I try to change it back to armv 6 but it seems like I cant the selection is disabled in the file.

Comment: It seems like I can only edit the $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) part. I set the architecture manually by typing "armv6", but after compiling I got an error in an assambly-ish looking file. Anybody knows how to change the architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your Info.plist doesn't contain a "Required device
   capabilities" key for armv7. If it exists, remove it.
2. Make sure that "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to **NO**.
3. Under your target's "Build Settings", Select "Other" in the "Architectures" row, and manually enter two values: **armv6** and **armv7**. Click outside the popover to save the manually entered values.

[image: iOS iPhone 3G not installing app Xcode 4.2 4.3 armv6 armv7]

Comment: ah, Im silly, that worked. But the app still doesnt get installed on my 3G

Comment: "not installed" = you don't even see the App icon on your device's home screen?

Comment: Does it work in the simulator? Did you make a Product ➞ Clean?
Also try to remove the device from Window ➞ Organizer ➞ Devices and re-add it.

Comment: Yes it works in the simulator, I also did a clean now and readded it in the organizer. I also rebooted xcode, the iphone and the imac but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: thanks for your effort but sadly it is set to NO. I also set "Required device Capabilities Array to armv6 and armv7 in the appname-info.plist and the valid Architectures to armv 6 armv 7 in the Build Settings. I´m pulling hairs here.

Comment: I removed the armv 7 in the device Capabilities Array but now I get an error dyld`dyld_fatal_error: in the assembly file again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13610/discussion-between-andreas-ley-and-dan)